# How to make a Edit text with only 10 lines and in each line 40 characters only

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to modify the android edittext such that it contains only 10 lines but in each line there are 40 characters only .

To get this i tries many ways like using 10 edittex and implementing textwatcher on every edittext 
But it do not fit , and handel counting of characters.
Or using key listener on edittext , but that is also not a solution working out.

What other possible way i can achieve it ?

Comment: why don't you try Tokenizing String?

Comment: You could try to use the editText with `android:maxLines=10` and `android:maxWidth=200dip` trying to play with the editText width to achieve 40 characters per line.

Comment: @zozlfelfo well different alphabets have different sizes. if i enter 40 i then it will take less space then 40 W. your approach not seems to be possible \